# Switch Image of a Handler in a e4 rcp

Tags: rcp, e4

I have an e4 rcp application and I want to extend my application with a toolbar item that should change the icon URL when the user execute it.

Is there any possibility to do this as I can do it in a MPart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `setIconURI` method of `MToolItem` in your handler for the tool item:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(MToolItem mitem)
{
  mitem.setIconURI("platform:/plugin/......");

  ... other code
}
```